# is there some way to let Wine use a local cache for gecko and mono? (instead of downloading them)

Tags: wine

I have to wait the gecko or mono repetitive downloads every time I update a wineprefix (I use one prefix per application).

winetricks has a local cache, why wine has not?

So, is there some way to let wine look for these files locally instead of downloading them every time?

For ex. now the download is ultra slow, I just cancelled it :(.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever Wine tries to find local installation, it will look in following directories:

- In most cases, the file(s) should be placed in `/usr/share/wine/gecko`.
- If you installed Wine in some $prefix rather than `/usr`, `$prefix/share/wine/gecko/` before `/usr/share/wine/gecko`. (e.g. if you installed it from source, then place the files in `/usr/local/share/wine/gecko`).
- If you're running Wine from build tree, Wine will try to find files in `$build_dir/../gecko directory`.
- Local cache, usually `~/.cache/wine`.

https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko

Download the files into `~/.cache/wine` and you'll be fine.

Comment: In my case creating a cache directory has been enough: `mkdir -p ~/.cache/wine` - wine now automatically saves the gecko runtime in it.